# How can I make a random selection of X% of cells be ="Y" and the rest of the cells equal to "N" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a list of outstanding property debts in one column and I'd like to model the outcome if a random selection of them are paid off (redeem).  This would be designated in an adjacent column, where redemption = "Y" and lack of redemption = "N".

These debts and their respective property characteristics are listed in adjacent columns. For example, there are columns designating the property as residential/commercial, condition, occupied/unoccupied, # of rentable units, etc.

Here's an example of a specific scenario I would like to model. What happens if 20% of the debts on 100% ownership interest residential lots redeem?

In other words, I'd like a random 20% of the cells in column "redeem Y/N" (in the case of the attached image - 1 cell) that meet the 100% interest, residential, lot criteria to be ="Y" and the rest to be = "N".

Here's a sample of my data:

[image: Here's an example sample of what my data looks like]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a sample of your data, so people could see which columns need to be tested and their headings.  If the data is sensitive, you can use fake names and numbers.  The easiest way is to upload a screenshot to eg, imgur.com, and edit your question to include the link to the picture.  Then someone here can edit the reference to make it directly visible in your answer.

Comment: @Bandersnatch The "data" is probably not sensitive. It sounds a lot like homework.

Comment: Not homework - for work actually. I wish I had done homework like this - then maybe I would know how to do this for work

Comment: Well, good. And thanks for the sample data, that should attract some answers.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be *exactly* 20%, or just an *average* (expected value) of 20%?

The second one is easy:

```
=IF(RAND() < 0.2,"Y", "N")
```

putting this formula in every cell in a column next to your data.

The first one is trickier. I'd do it by using RAND() to assign a number to each entry, then sorting your data by the random result. Then assign the first 1/5 of your data to have the Yes value.

Comment: Thanks! I was wanting exactly 20%, or rather 20% rounded to the nearest integer.